# Can't address memory further than 64 kB with segment registers

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos, dosbox

I'm trying to access memory in data section with segment registers. However, when reaching addresses near 64 kB instead of data segment content I'm getting several bytes of garbage followed by zeroes. The code looks like this:

```
section .data
    start: db 42
    other: times 100000 db 2

section .text

_main:  
    mov ax, ds
    add ax, 4062
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, start

    mov al, [ds:si]
```

For segments less than specified in the code register `al` contains 2 as expected, but starting somewhere around segment offset 4062 (which is approximately 64 kB) the values firstly seem random, then just zeroes.

The executable's hexdump revealed that it does contain entire data section. What could be the problem then, if the all data is there and segments for lower addresses are accessed correctly?

I'm using NASM compiler and DOSBox for launching the executable.
This is how I compile the code:

```
nasm -f bin src/main.asm -o main.exe
```

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. You just offset the current `ds`, we can't tell how that's initialized. Also you did not show how you linked your program. In case you tried to make a `.com` file, be advised the maximum size is 65280 bytes which might explain what you are seeing.

Comment: With the line `other: times 100000 db 2` you try to define a 100,000 byte array, but the segment limit in _Real Mode_ is 65,536 bytes. So you're crossing segment boundaries _in a segment_, represented with a _section_.

Comment: `nasm -f bin` will not create an `.exe` no matter if you call it that (unless you manually included an exe header which is unlikely). You will get a flat binary which will be loaded as a `.com` file. To get a proper exe you will need to use `-f obj` or `-f as86` and use a linker. `dosbox` will only load the first ~64k of `.com` files.

Comment: It will not load `.com` files larger than that. It will load `.exe` files. But as I said, it's not about the name. The `.exe` files have special header describing the program. `nasm -f bin` does not add that  header.

Comment: @Jester : or switch to using FASM and use `format MZ`  if you want an EXE.

Comment: @Jester, thank you very much for clarification. So, if I understood you correctly, dosbox will load an executable made in a right way?

Comment: Yes, dosbox (and DOS in general) will load large `.exe` **format** (not name) files.

Comment: If you can get a copy of a Microsoft 16 bit tool set, it will include codeview, which is a text based GUI source level debugger, and programmers workbench, h2inc,which will convert .H files for C programs to .INC files for asm files, as well as a C compiler and MASM 6.11. It can build .COM files or .EXE files of various types, small, medium, large, huge, ... .

Comment: @Jester just letting know that even if .com file can be that "large" still there should be space for stack (SP).